# How to connect to database created in VS2015 SQL Server Data Tools

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, localdb, sql-server-data-tools

I have Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server Data Tools installed. I can see database, tables etc, and run queries in Visual Studio. However, I cannot connect to database using third party application.

[image]

It seems, that the SQL Server service isn't listening on any port:

[image]

[image]

How to connect to that database? Or how to make that service to listen a port?

Comment: You're using SQL Server Express **LocalDB** - which is an "on-demand" server - it only spins up when your app is running, and shuts down when you stop your app. Therefore, you don't see it on your system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Express LocalDB (commonly referred to as just "LocalDB") runs as a background process initiated by a Login, not as a service. It can only accept local connections. The instances can be started manually using the **SQLLocalDB.exe** utility, *or* if an application is a .NET app or implements the LocalDB API, then attempting to connect via the `(localdb)\...` syntax will automatically start the instance if it is not already running. LocalDB instances also automatically shutdown about 5 minutes after the last connection to it is closed.

You can see what instances you have by running the following in a command window:

```
SQLLocalDB i
```

You can start an instance by running:

```
SQLLocalDB s ProjectsV12
```

You can instance-specific info by running:

```
SQLLocalDB i ProjectsV12
```

You can stop the instance by running:

```
SQLLocalDB p ProjectsV12
```

You can connect to an instance to test, even if it is not currently running, by running the following command line (give it a moment to spin up before it connects the first time):

```
SQLCMD -S (localdb)\ProjectsV12 -Q "SELECT @@SERVERNAME;"
```

That will return a value along the lines of:

> MachineName\LOCALDB#xxxxxxxx

where each "x" is a hex digit (i.e. 0-9, A-F). Or, if it is a shared instance, the name will be in the following format:

> MachineName\LOCALDB#SHxxxxxx

Each running instance also has a named-pipes name in the form of:

> np:\.\pipe\LOCALDB#xxxxxxxx\tsql\query

where each "x" is again a hex digit. And again, if it is a shared instance, then the first two hex digits are replaced with "SH".

The main difference between the two syntaxes (i.e. `(localdb)\...` vs `np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#xxxxxxxx\tsql\query`) is that using the named-pipes syntax will *not* automatically start the instance if it is not already running: only the `(localdb)\...` syntax can do that as it gets routed through the special LOCALDB API.

Comment: Thank you so much! I used "(localdb)\ProjectsV12" in Hostname\ip field